# Open a webview with buttons in a fragment

Tags: java, url, button, android-fragments, android-webview

i have this simple code in my java class but it not run. where is the error?
i want open in a webview different sites from a fragment with some buttons...Thanks in advance for help me

```
public class SitoFragment extends Fragment {


private WebView URL13, URL14; 
private Button button12,button13;

    button12 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button12);
    button12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            URL13 = (WebView) URL13.findViewById(R.id.webviewsito);
            URL13.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            URL13.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
            URL13.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            URL13.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            URL13.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxx.com");

        }
    });

    button13 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button13);
    button13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            URL14 = (WebView) URL14.findViewById(R.id.webviewsito);
            URL14.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            URL14.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
            URL14.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            URL14.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            URL14.loadUrl("http://www.xxxx.com");

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "not run" are you getting an error? What is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: i expect to open, when i click a button,1 webview in a fragment. But  "setOnClickListener" gives me an error.